# How do I get and show results of autocomplete in other textbox

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I have two textboxes and I want to use autocomplete in jQuery. I want to show the results of a search from the first textbox in the second textbox, like this :

```
First TextBox                  Second TextBox
   Se....                          server
                                   serve
                                   search
                                   seat
                                   .
                                   .
                                   .
                                   and ...
```

How can I search in the first textbox and have results appear  in second textbox?

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) - besides, in terms of usability, seems a bit ackward doesn't it ?